# Tomcat upgrade 7 to 8.5

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

What is the migration path for Tomcat 7 to 8.5 ? I seen on tomcat website there migration guides only have information for tomcat 8 to 8.5. Can we upgrade from 7 to 8.5 ? If someone has migrated how is their experience with tomcat 8.5 ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I think you just have to read both [Tomcat 8.0.x Migration Guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html) and [Tomcat 8.5.x Migration Guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html).